# i'm trying to subtract these two dataframes but NaNs apear instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

[the image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kECAq.png)
I made all of the dataframes needed and all the values but I don't know why NaNs appear.

MY CODE:

```
`import pandas as pd 

red_data = pd.DataFrame([[255,0,20],[210,30,0],[220,40,5],[240,10,30], 
[225,60,20]])
green_data = pd.DataFrame([[0,255,0],[10,240,5],[0,240,20],[5,220,30], 
[30,230,10]])
blue_data = pd.DataFrame([[30,10,220],[10,10,255],[0,0,240],[25,15,210], 
[0,20,220]])

red_data.columns =[["R","G","B"]]
green_data.columns =[["R","G","B"]]
blue_data.columns =[["R","G","B"]]

print(red_data)
print(green_data)
print(blue_data)


Feature1 = red_data.loc[:,"R"]-red_data.loc[:,"G"]
Feature2 = 2*red_data.loc[:,"B"] - red_data.loc [:,"R"] - red_data.loc 
[:,"G"]

print(Feature1)
print(Feature2)`
```

Comment: `red_data.loc[:,"R"]` this should have error as you have multi-indexed columns

Comment: So I had to access the values and use `.values`

Comment: If you simply name your columns as `red_data.columns =["R","G","B"]`, etc. rather than the nested you're using then your code would work.  Any reason for the nested list naming?

Comment: i am a student (not an expert)* so mostly I don't know what  I'm actually doing but thank you that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the relevant lines of your code with

```
red_data.columns =["R","G","B"]
green_data.columns =["R","G","B"]
blue_data.columns =["R","G","B"]
```

I think you created multiindex columns, possibly inadvertently